# How do I join Two threads class in the Tester?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two Thread class. buyThread and sellThread .Inside the tester program, I need to declare and create 2 threads object belong to buyThread and sellThread, and do a run and join threads.

```
Thread bt[] = new Thread[2]; // declare and create 2 threads object
    Thread st[] = new Thread[2]; // declare and create 2 threads object

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        bt[i] = new BuyThread(rand1, rand2, stock);
        bt[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        st[i] = new SellThread(rand1, rand2, stock);
        st[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // Can I do it this way for each Thread ?
    {
        try {
            bt[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            st[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what is the problem? you declare 4 threads anyway (but you don't start any of them.) -- ook, you edited the question but still what is the problem? .join method will let the main thread to wait until all threads are finished

Comment: May I check is this the correct way to write a join() ?

Comment: Can I just write                                                    for (int i=0; i < 2; i ++)
{
try
{
st[i].join();
bt[i]                                                                 }
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}

Comment: Well, you already know what will be the threads to join (0, 1) so you can just do st[0].join(); st[1].join(); and avoid for

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? As a side note, I recommend to [_not_ extend Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/541506/836214) and instead use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to manage your tasks...

Comment: You can write for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { st[i].join(); bt[i].join(); } too. No indexs problems (if you keep 2 indexs)

Answer (score 0):

Your join is fine.

Note that you're waiting for both `BuyThread` instances to complete first, and then waiting for both `SellThread` instances to complete (in that order).

The benefit of shoving everything into an array is that you only need to add new instances of each `Buy`/`Sell` thread class into the array, and your app will wait for all of them to finish.

Isn't that what you wanted?

**Edit:** As mentioned in comments, you should implement runnable instead of extending the `Thread` class. That's cleaner. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread?lq=1) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much , i will carry on from here.